# button this binding pointing to window

Tags: javascript, this

I am trying to get the button that an event handler is on, I tried simply reaching it by `this` but I am getting the window.  This doesn't make sense to me as the event handler is not an arrow function.
`removeBank` is attached to `delButton`

```
getBankList = async (error, event) => {
  const tBody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]
    const values = event.returnValues;
    ...

    var row = document.createElement("tr"); 

    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    ...
    }

    const delButton = document.createElement("button");
    delButton.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-icon btn-delete");
    delButton.setAttribute("onclick", "removeBank();");
    const delIcon = document.createElement("i");
    delIcon.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-trash-alt");
    delButton.appendChild(delIcon);
    row.appendChild(delButton);

    tBody.appendChild(row);
}

removeBank = async function() {
  if (window.KYCinstance) {
    console.log(this);
  } else {
    throw new Error('KYC instance not loaded')
  }    
}
```

Comment: Do not use setAttribute to bind events! Use addEventListener

Comment: Do not use `delButton.setAttribute("onclick", "removeBank();");`, ever. You're in JS, use normal modern eventhandling: `delButton.addEventListener("click", evt => removeBank(evt));`. As for getting the button... it's _in the event_, just use `event.target`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use addEventListener to bind events.

```
delButton.addEventListener("click", removeBank);
```

Comment: is delButton.onclick=removeBank a bad idea ?

Comment: @jonathanHeindl It's in poor taste most every time due to extensibility, readability, and side effects. Honestly the longer you code web the more you'll probably gain the opinion that it's annoying to have event attributes on HTMLElements. I, personally, wish they would just do away with them.

Answer (score 3):

reach it by `event.target` which is the button

Comment: or since your setting it in javascritp anyways just pass it along

Comment: this got me the <i> tag that is a child of the button

Comment: did you add the listener to the <i> tag as well oO ?